# Problem with Joystick HID descriptor readout

Tags: hid

I bought a used Joystick (Speedlink Phantom Hawk), which I can't return. I contacted the Support from Speedlink, but they cant help me with this. It is a known Problem for them, but they dont have a Solution.

The Z-Rotation Axis (twist axis) has a weird offset and doesn't read out the full Motion, it is centred at readout 180, and only uses about 20-30% of the IRL range. I tried everything conventional, and everything driver related, nothing helped (Windows driver, Speedlink Joystick Driver, and alternative drivers).

From Hours of trying to fix this Problem, I got to figure out what exactly is not working correctly, however I couldn't find a way to solve it.

Using "Free Device Monitoring Studio" I am able to read out the HID descriptor and the Values send by the Joystick.

**The Problem is,** that the Joystick has 2 Z-Axis readouts, the first one is the actual Z-Rotation Axis with its full range, the second Z-Axis is the thrust Slider, and the Rz-Axis is again the Z-Rotation, but only part of the Range with the weird offset.

The actual Z-Axis gives values between 35-230 over the full twist range.

So it's not a faulty sensor.

The Joystick driver is build on top of the Windows driver, and only gives the ability to centre the Axis.

**The Question now is,** is there a way to get it working again?

Either by editing the HID descriptor, or by making it that Windows reads the actual Z-Axis instead of the false Rz-Axis?

One readout of sent packages looks like this:

Report ID:-1

X[0..255]/[0..255]: 128

Y[0..255]/[0..255]: 125

Z[0..255]/[0..255]: 146 <--- actual twist Axis

Z[0..255]/[0..255]: 127 <---- Thrust Slider

Rz[0..255]/[0..255]: 174 <----fake/false twist Axis.

Hat Switch[0x0..0x7]/[0x0..0x13b]: 0xf

BUTTON1 pressed: 0

BUTTON2 pressed: 0

BUTTON3 pressed: 0

BUTTON4 pressed: 0

BUTTON5 pressed: 0

BUTTON6 pressed: 0

BUTTON7 pressed: 0

BUTTON8 pressed: 0

BUTTON9 pressed: 0

BUTTON10 pressed: 0

BUTTON11 pressed: 0

BUTTON12 pressed: 0

Unknown: 0

Unknown: 0

Unknown: 0

Unknown: 0

Unknown: 0

Unknown: 0

Unknown: 1

Unknown: 0

The HID Descriptor reads out this:

05 01 09 04 A1 01 09 00 A1 02 09 30 15 00 25 FF

35 00 45 FF 65 00 55 00 75 08 95 01 81 02 09 31

81 02 09 32 81 02 09 32 81 02 09 35 81 02 09 39

25 07 46 3B 01 65 14 75 04 81 42 05 09 19 01 29

0C 25 01 45 01 65 00 75 01 95 0C 81 02 95 08 81

03 C1 00 06 00 FF 09 00 A1 02 09 02 25 FF 45 FF

75 08 95 07 91 02 C1 00 C1 00

Which when Parsed gives this:

0x05, 0x01, // Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)

0x09, 0x04, // Usage (Joystick)

0xA1, 0x01, // Collection (Application)

0x09, 0x00, // Usage (Undefined)

0xA1, 0x02, // Collection (Logical)

0x09, 0x30, // Usage (X)

0x15, 0x00, // Logical Minimum (0)

0x25, 0xFF, // Logical Maximum (-1)

0x35, 0x00, // Physical Minimum (0)

0x45, 0xFF, // Physical Maximum (-1)

0x65, 0x00, // Unit (None)

0x55, 0x00, // Unit Exponent (0)

0x75, 0x08, // Report Size (8)

0x95, 0x01, // Report Count (1)

0x81, 0x02, // Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

0x09, 0x31, // Usage (Y)

0x81, 0x02, // Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

0x09, 0x32, // Usage (Z)

0x81, 0x02, // Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

0x09, 0x32, // Usage (Z)

0x81, 0x02, // Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

0x09, 0x35, // Usage (Rz)

0x81, 0x02, // Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

0x09, 0x39, // Usage (Hat switch)

0x25, 0x07, // Logical Maximum (7)

0x46, 0x3B, 0x01, // Physical Maximum (315)

0x65, 0x14, // Unit (System: English Rotation, Length: Centimeter)

0x75, 0x04, // Report Size (4)

0x81, 0x42, // Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,Null State)

0x05, 0x09, // Usage Page (Button)

0x19, 0x01, // Usage Minimum (0x01)

0x29, 0x0C, // Usage Maximum (0x0C)

0x25, 0x01, // Logical Maximum (1)

0x45, 0x01, // Physical Maximum (1)

0x65, 0x00, // Unit (None)

0x75, 0x01, // Report Size (1)

0x95, 0x0C, // Report Count (12)

0x81, 0x02, // Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

0x95, 0x08, // Report Count (8)

0x81, 0x03, // Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)

0xC1, 0x00, // End Collection

0x06, 0x00, 0xFF, // Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFF00)

0x09, 0x00, // Usage (0x00)

0xA1, 0x02, // Collection (Logical)

0x09, 0x02, // Usage (0x02)

0x25, 0xFF, // Logical Maximum (-1)

0x45, 0xFF, // Physical Maximum (-1)

0x75, 0x08, // Report Size (8)

0x95, 0x07, // Report Count (7)

0x91, 0x02, // Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)

0xC1, 0x00, // End Collection

0xC1, 0x00, // End Collection

// 106 bytes

Comment: I can't explain the odd range values you are experiencing, but I think the HID report descriptor is not quite right - but that is probably not so important if the vendor supplies a device driver for it. The report descriptor seems to exhibit a classic error of trying to encode Logical Maximum 255 as 0x25FF (which is -1) instead of the more correct 0x26FF00 (which is +255). Also, End Collection should not have a data item i.e. it should be just 0xC0, not 0xC100. i'm surprised that Windows accepted that...but I guess it is more expedient to add a quirk to the parser than it is to fix the device.

Comment: @aja Thanks for that answer. Is it possible to edit the parser via registry, or do I have to go into sys32 and edit it there?